# How to use PCcli command to generate hundreds of peptide coordinates?

Tags: pandas, string, mapping, call, biopython

There is a PCcli command [https://pypi.org/project/PeptideConstructor/] which construct the *.pdb* file of a given peptide sequence however I couldn't understand how to use it for hundreds of peptide sequences. Its usage for single peptide is like this:

```
pip install PeptideConstructor

PCcli -s AaDdKSQym -o output.pdb
```

Here the characters coming after -s flag is the peptide sequence and -o flag is used to name the output .pdb file. I have a list of peptide sequences in a .csv file and would like to use PCcli command to produce the .pdb's of these sequences.

Let's say I have an 100 sequences and read the 'Sequences' column with `pd.read_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("PeptideSequences.csv")
```

Then with a for loop I tried to place every sequence line after -s flag and give the sequence name to the output .pdb files in the same manner.

```
for i in range(100):

    PCcli -s str(df.loc[i,'Sequences']) -o str(df.loc[i,'Sequences']).pdb
```

However, I got invalid syntax error. Could you please help me to use the command? I would also be grateful for alternative usage suggestions. For ex. mapping the sequences

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please post the full error? (as text). I wonder about possibility of [mre] in your case.

Comment: still I dont get how the singles peptide folds :  de novo folding, homology modeling, molecular dynamics (MD) simulation, or deep-learning-based method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
from subprocess import call

for seq in df['Sequences']:
    call(['PCcli', '-s', seq, '-o', f'{seq}.pdb'])
```